Why Is the Following Proof of a Finite Nonempty Totally Ordered Set Containing Its Maximum Wrong?
I wish to prove the result suggested in the title without induction on the cardinality of set. Here is my approach:
Let $S$ be a finite nonempty totally ordered set, i.e. $S=\lbrace x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\rbrace$, where $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer. For the purpose of contradiction, assume that $S$ does not have a maximum. Thus, for each $x_{i_{1}}\in S$, there exists some $x_{i_{2}}\in S$ such that $x_{i_{1}}<x_{i_{2}}$. Similarly, for $x_{i_{2}}$ there exists some $x_{i_{3}}\in S$ such that $x_{i_{2}}<x_{i_{3}}$. Continuing in this fashion we get $x_{i_{1}}<x_{i_{2}}<x_{i_{3}}<\cdots<x_{i_{n}}<\cdots$, which implies that $S$ is infinite, a contradiction.
I am very doubtful about the validity of the above argument. Could you please point out if and why it is wrong?

Seems fine to me but in essence you are still performing induction, now over the minimal number of elements that $S$ must contain (i.e. you are showing that $\lvert S\rvert\ge n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$).

"Continuing in this fashion [...]" is using induction (informally). What makes you think the argument is incorrect though?

@TimSeifert Just a feeling, as a newbie it did not seem rigorous enough.

Well, to make it more rigorous, you may want to make the induction you are informally performing more explicit. In particular, try to formulate exactly, what statement you are inducting over. But the argument itself is perfectly fine as is

Another approach, which is constructive, is a variant of the algorithm called online bubble sort: (1) Mark $x_1$ as your current favorite, $x’$. (2) Successively for each $i \in {2, \ldots, n}$, if $x’ < x_i$, then update your favorite. (3) Now, since $<$ is a total order, $x’=\max_<{x_1, \ldots, x_n}$.
